# Can not open an activity multiple time from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

i want to make an app which shows a flash message. i am listening to `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` . when onReceive() called i am starting an activity.
first time when onReceive() is called it starts activity but next time it wont. here is my code

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            this.abortBroadcast();
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,Start.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        arg0.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

i am aborting the broadcast so message wont go in the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on "launchMode" in your AndroidManifest file for "Start" activity. Use launchMode = "standart" or handle onNewIntent method in your activity.

Comment: Even if you change the launch mode in manifest file,the launch mode setting in the intent which start the activity will take the precedence.

Comment: It could be a problem. If you launch new activity from outside of activity you should use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, but it is the same as launchMode = "singleTask". In this case. new activity will not be lauched. It could be 2 options to solve the problem: 1 - use activity.onNewIntent or 2 - get last started activity in your reciever(use Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) and lauch new activity from it.

Comment: @akelix if i get rid of`this.clearAboardBroadcast()` then it works fine. but i do not want to do that. and what is activity.onNewIntent()where i have to override it ?

Comment: @akelix how i can get the last started activity from receiver ? can you please help me out. m exustaed

Comment: If you want use the same activity that was already launched. you could override method onNewIntent in your Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent). Or you could create instance of Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks(your instance should have field Activity that is set in method onActivityCreated) and  register it in Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacs(...). Make this instance available from public static method and use it in your reciever.